# A damage file system vfat of usb

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

When I run this command `sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdb` getting following error:

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem

0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.

 Automatically removing dirty bit.

Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"

Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)

       512 bytes per logical sector
      8192 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors

First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)

         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
   7569408 bytes per FAT (= 14784 sectors)

Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)

Data area starts at byte 15155200 (sector 29600)
   1890310 data clusters (15485419520 bytes)
32 sectors/track, 64 heads
         0 hidden sectors
  30274560 sectors total

Both FATs appear to be corrupt. Giving up.
```

Any help/suggestion here!

Comment: Are you sure the USB flash drive is still good?  USB flash drives, often fail in this manner.  Check your `dmesg` for I/O errors.